# Custom ListView with cheboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, checked

how i can know when all checkboxes in a custom listview in a android application are checked? I have a custom listview and i just want to know when all checkboxes in the list are checked and show a message to the user, sorry for my english.

this is the code for my adapter, but its not work...

```
public class MeuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinhaItem>
{

    private final List<LinhaItem> lista;
    private final Activity contexto;
    private final boolean[] pegos;
    private double total = 0;

    public MeuAdapter(Activity contexto, List<LinhaItem> lista)
    {
        super(contexto, R.layout.produtos, lista);
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.lista = lista;
        pegos = new boolean[this.lista.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.lista.size(); i++)
        {
            pegos[i] = false;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        protected TextView texto;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
        protected EditText edit;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = null;
        final int posicao = position;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = contexto.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.produtos, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkProduto);
            viewHolder.edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtValor);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    LinhaItem elemento = (LinhaItem) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    elemento.setSelecionado(buttonView.isChecked());
                    if(elemento.Selecionado())
                    {
                        pegos[posicao] = true;
                    }
                    total += lista.get(posicao).getValor();

                    boolean cheia = true;

                    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
                    {
                        cheia = pegos[i];
                        //Toast.makeText(contexto, "pego["+i+"]"+pegos[i], 10000).show();
                    }

                    if(cheia)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(contexto, "Compra finalizada,  valor total: " + total, 10000).show();
                    }
                }   
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));

        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.texto.setText(lista.get(position).getTexto());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(lista.get(position).Selecionado());
        holder.edit.setText(Double.toString((lista.get(position).getValor())));



        return view;
    }

}
```

My new code is that:

```
package br.com.boitata.cadastroprodutos;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class CadastroProdutosActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnInserir;
    private EditText txtDescricao;
    private EditText txtValor;
    private TextView txtTotal;
    private ListView lstProdutos;
    private ProdutoBD bd;
    private MeuAdapter adapter;

    List<Produto> lista;
    List<LinhaItem> linhas;

    private double total = 0;

    public void preencheLista(List<Produto> lp, ListView lista)
    {
        int tam = lp.size();        
        linhas = new ArrayList<LinhaItem>();

        for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        {
            Produto p = lp.get(i);              
            linhas.add(getLinha(p.getDescricao()));
        }

        adapter = new MeuAdapter(this, linhas);

        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, valores);

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public LinhaItem getLinha(String texto)
    {
        return new LinhaItem(texto);
    }   


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_produtos);

        btnInserir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInserir);
        txtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        txtValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtValor);
        txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);
        lstProdutos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstProdutos);

        lstProdutos.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);       


        bd = new ProdutoBD(getApplicationContext());


        lista = bd.listaProdutos();         


        preencheLista(lista, lstProdutos);          


        btnInserir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String checados = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
                {
                    checados += "pego[" + i + "]" + " " + pegos[i] + " - ";
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checados, 40000).show();
            /*  Produto p = new Produto();
                p.setDescricao(txtDescricao.getText().toString());
                p.setValor(Double.parseDouble(txtValor.getText().toString()));
                bd.insere(p);           

                lista = bd.listaProdutos();

                preencheLista(lista, lstProdutos);

                int i = 0;
                total = 0;
                while(i < lista.size())
                {
                    p = lista.get(i);
                    total += p.getValor();
                    i++;
                }

                txtTotal.setText("Total: " + Double.toString(total));*/

            }
        });

    }

    private boolean[] pegos;
    private boolean[] passados;

    public class MeuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinhaItem>
    {

        private final List<LinhaItem> lista;
        private final Activity contexto;        
        private double total = 0;
        private  int qtde = 0;


        public MeuAdapter(Activity contexto, List<LinhaItem> lista)
        {
            super(contexto, R.layout.produtos, lista);
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Construindo", 10000).show();
            this.contexto = contexto;
            this.lista = lista;
            qtde = this.lista.size();
            pegos = new boolean[qtde];
            passados = new boolean[qtde];
            for(int i = 0; i < this.lista.size(); i++)
            {
                pegos[i] = false;
                passados[i] = false;
            }
        }

        public class ViewHolder
        {
            protected TextView texto;
            protected CheckBox checkbox;
            protected EditText edit;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = null;
            final int posicao = position;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = contexto.getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.produtos, null);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
                viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkProduto);
                viewHolder.edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtValor);

                viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        LinhaItem elemento = (LinhaItem) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                        elemento.setSelecionado(buttonView.isChecked());

                        pegos[posicao] = isChecked;

                        if(elemento.Selecionado())
                        {
                            pegos[posicao] = true;
                            qtde--;
                        }
                        else if(qtde < lista.size() && passados[posicao])
                        {
                            qtde++;
                        }                       

                        total += lista.get(posicao).getValor();

                        boolean cheia = true;

                        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if(!pegos[i])
                            {
                                cheia = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            //Toast.makeText(contexto, "pego["+i+"]"+pegos[i], 10000).show();
                        }

                        if(cheia || qtde == 0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Compra finalizada,  valor total: " + total, 10000).show();
                        }

                    //  Toast.makeText(contexto, "Quantidade não selecionada: " + qtde, 5000).show();
                    }   
                });

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
                viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));

            }
            else
            {
                view = convertView;
                ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.texto.setText(lista.get(position).getTexto());
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(lista.get(position).Selecionado());
            holder.edit.setText(Double.toString((lista.get(position).getValor())));

            passados[posicao] = true;

            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

this works just for the rows currently appearing...

Comment: you just use baseadapter with custom layout, and outside of that adapter you create array with booleans. Inside of adapter you work with that array and on click you create method to check how many checked buttons are now. Then you use for statement to check all items if they are checked... did you even search?

Comment: i was trying it, but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if you checked the last unchecked `CheckBox` in the list's rows you could use several approaches. Here is one:

```
boolean allChecked = true;
for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
     if (!pegos[i]) {
          // it appears that one of our ChckBoxes is currently unchecked so
          // we already know that not all CheckBoxes are checked 
          allChecked = false;
          break;
     }
if (allChecked) {
    // if we get here and allChecked is true than all CheckBoxes are checked
    Toast.makeText(contexto, "All checked!!", 10000).show();
}
```

To avoid looping that boolean array each time the user checks a `CheckBox` you could have a `int` field in the adapter which initially is the size of the boolean array. When the user checks a `CheckBox` you decrease with `1` from that field, when the user unchecks a `CheckBox` you increase with `1` that field. In the same listener you test to see if that field is `0` in which case all the `CheckBoxes` are checked.

Comment: Luksprog, the first approach is not working (i was doing it), in the second, aparently when a move to the next row (scrolling) the number of unchecked rows increases because in the next row the checkbox is unchecked...

Comment: @DaniloSilva Is your code working perfectly? If you check some `CheckBoxes` and scroll the `ListView` arounf up[and down, things are ok?

Comment: @DaniloSilva Your adapter code is not correct. I've rewritten it and it should do what you want. The code is here https://gist.github.com/4246480

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code -

```
public class MeuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private final List<LinhaItem> lista;
    private final Activity contexto;
    private final boolean[] pegos;
    private double total = 0;

    public MeuAdapter(Activity contexto, List<LinhaItem> lista)
    {
        super(contexto, R.layout.produtos, lista);
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.lista = lista;
        pegos = new boolean[this.lista.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.lista.size(); i++)
        {
            pegos[i] = false;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        protected TextView texto;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
        protected EditText edit;
    }

    public boolean isAllChecked() {
        boolean allChecked = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
             if (!pegos[i]) {
                  allChecked = false;
                  break;
             }
        return allChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = null;
        final int posicao = position;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = contexto.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.produtos, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkProduto);
            viewHolder.edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtValor);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    LinhaItem elemento = (LinhaItem) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    elemento.setSelecionado(buttonView.isChecked());
                    if(elemento.Selecionado())
                    {
                        pegos[posicao] = true;
                    }
                    total += lista.get(posicao).getValor();

                    boolean cheia = true;

                    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
                    {
                        cheia = pegos[i];
                        //Toast.makeText(contexto, "pego["+i+"]"+pegos[i], 10000).show();
                    }

                    if(cheia)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(contexto, "Compra finalizada,  valor total: " + total, 10000).show();
                    }
                }   
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));

        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(lista.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.texto.setText(lista.get(position).getTexto());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(lista.get(position).Selecionado());
        holder.edit.setText(Double.toString((lista.get(position).getValor())));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about like that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textStrings = new String[]{"I'm Bob", "I'm Alice"};
    checkedArray = new boolean[textStrings.length];

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(this, textStrings, checkedArray));
}

private String[] textStrings;
private boolean[] checkedArray;

private class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater pInflater;
    private Holder pHolder;
    private String[] pTextStrings;
    private boolean[] pCheckedArray;
    private Context pContext;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, String[] textStrings,
            boolean[] checkedArray) {
        this.pContext = context;
        this.pTextStrings = textStrings;
        this.pCheckedArray = checkedArray;
        this.pInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        makeAllFalse(pCheckedArray);

    }
    private void makeAllFalse(boolean[] pCheckedArray2) {
        for (Boolean b : pCheckedArray2) {
            b = false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pTextStrings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = this.pInflater.inflate(R.layout.listing, null);
        this.pHolder = new Holder();
        this.pHolder.chbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chbox);
        this.pHolder.chbox.setText(pTextStrings[position]);

        final int positionItem = position;
        this.pHolder.chbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        checkedArray[positionItem] = isChecked;

                        if (countChecked())
                            Toast.makeText(pContext,
                                    "All checkboxes are checked",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(this.pHolder);

        return convertView;
    }

    private boolean countChecked() {
        for (boolean b : checkedArray) {
            if (!b) {
                Log.d("xxx", "not all is checked");
                return false;
            }
        }
        Log.d("xxx", "all is checked");
        return true;

    }

    private class Holder {
        CheckBox chbox;
    }

}

}
```

And layouts are, first main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Text Here"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is for listing layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item" >
    </CheckBox>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's just an example. If you don't know any, just post under my answer.

Sample:

[image: not all clicked]

> 12-09 15:53:32.290: D/xxx(620): not all is checked

[image]

> 12-09 15:54:04.150: D/xxx(620): all is checked

Comment: Lumma, i modified my code a litle to match with your, but still not working properly, aparently this works just for the rows currently appearing (in my case 3), but my list have 19 itens and when i scroll and check the others just the 3 first positions of the array are true (checked). I hope you undestand what i try to say, my english is not good...

Comment: are you trying to say that you dynamically add items to list? by the way.. check the place where I use LayoutInflater and how I initiate it. You use inflater in getView, and I make it in constructor. Please write more, did you find out anything more?

Comment: well I've checked and my solution and this works for items even more than 10, it works also for 20 and more

Comment: My list is populated from a database, the code that Luksprog rewriten is working for me, thank you anyway.